# В чём причина ошибки при создании проекта на Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, composer

```
$ laravel new laravel-app
```

Crafting application...

In RequestException.php line 52:

Error creating resource: [message] fopen(http://cabinet.laravel.com/latest.zip): failed to open stream: ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒
  ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒, ▒.▒. ▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒, ▒▒▒ ▒▒
  ▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒-▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒.

[file] C:\Users\andrew\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\StreamHandler.php
  [line] 323

In StreamHandler.php line 252:

Error creating resource: [message] fopen(http://cabinet.laravel.com/latest.zip): failed to open stream: ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒
  ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒, ▒.▒. ▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒, ▒▒▒ ▒▒
  ▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒-▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒.

[file] C:\Users\andrew\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\StreamHandler.php
  [line] 323

Answer (score 1):

Ну очевидно же, что не может открыть файл `http://cabinet.laravel.com/latest.zip`. Проверил файл на доступность. Оказалось, что его кто-то блокирует. Сам laravel или провайдер или РКН. Запустил через Тор, файл прекрасно загрузился.

Comment: Как в браузере обойти понятно - а как в консоли?

Comment: Непростой вопрос. Тор при запуске создаёт прокси сервер. Каким-то образом нужно настроиться на него.